# seting rtprio limit in system without PAM

Tags: ulimit, sysctl

I have minimal linux system without PAM (custom complied linux based appliance) and I want to set system wide (all users) rtprio to 99.

My idea is to do this with help of sysctl. But looking on output of sysctl -a, I didn't see any parameter related to rtprio.

May somebody hint me what is best way to permanently set rtprio for all users and without using PAM?

br

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation it looks like best solution (at the moment) is to use prlimit from util-linux. Simply use i.e. "prlimit --rtprio=99 command_to_run" as root.

It is sad that sysctl can't be used for some limits (i.e RTPRIO can't be set via sysctl...)